# D3 listening to "end" event of a transition

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm learning D3 and following this lesson: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EpeOzq8eDYk&index=8&list=PL6il2r9i3BqH9PmbOf5wA5E1wOG3FT22p

Why is `.each("end", function() {...}` producing this error? `Uncaught TypeError: callback.call is not a function`

```
var canvas3 = d3.select("#doooo")
                .append("svg")
                .attr("width", 500)
                .attr("height", 500)
var circle3 = canvas3.append("circle")
                .attr("cx", 50)
                .attr("cy", 50)
                .attr("r", 25)

circle3.transition()
    .duration(1500)
    .attr("cx", 150)
    .each("end", function() { console.log("This is producing an error"); })
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Ah, `.each("end", function() {...})` (version 3) seems to have been replaced by `.on("end", ...)` in version 4.